# jquery select problem

Tags: jquery

Say I have an unordered list like so:

```
<ul>
<li>Some Text</li>
<li>Some Text</li>
<li>Some Text</li>
<li>Some Text</li>
</ul>
```

I want to use jquery so that when I click a "li", the background changes to blue. So I do this:

```
    $('li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

And the "active" class has as background of blue. However, I can't figure out how to make it so that when I click another "li", the other "li" that has a background of blue stops having a background of blue. I guess what I'm trying to say is how to make only one "li" have a background of blue at a time--using jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('li').click(function() {
  $('li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

This approach selects the current `.active` and removes the class from it before applying it to the one you just clicked.

Comment: Yes that does it but it also removes the active class from the one you click on. I need the last one that was clicked to have the blue background.

Comment: oh nevermind...I messed something up in my code. Now it works. Thanks a lot!